# weird gui component edges!

Tags: android, user-interface, edges

I developed my application and tested it on android emulator 1.6, 2.1 & 2.2 and on HTC Magic
its running PERFECTLY and the gui components look very neat...

However, when I tested it on Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 the gui components are looking fuzzy :S...please have a look

[image]

...Have anyone faced such a problem? Any suggestions to solve it?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for it, adding this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml solved the problem...